# openlayers 5 vector source does not clear, after calling clear function

Tags: vector, openlayers, openlayers-5

In my openlayers 5 (based on a angular 6 app), I am implementing a functionality where you search for something, query the db, the db brings back some geoJSON and I render this geoJSON data in a ol vector layer.

There are two different ways to search, so there are two different forms that bring back geoJSOn to the same ol vector.

Of course, before rendering the data, I have to clear out the layer.

This is my code

```
ngOnInit() {//initialize some params and the ol map
    //bring results-as you type - pure angular
    this.results = this.myForm.valueChanges.pipe(
      switchMap( formdata => this.mapcmsService.searchName(formdata.name, formdata.cepDrop))
    );//pipe

    this.tilesource = new OlXYZ({
      url:'http://tile.stamen.com/terrain/{z}/{x}/{y}.jpg'
    });

    this.tilelayer = new OlTileLayer({
      source: this.tilesource
    });

    this.vectorsource = new VectorSource({});

    this.vectorlayer = new VectorLayer({
      source: this.vectorsource
    });

    this.view = new OlView({
      center: OlProj.fromLonLat([6.661594, 50.433237]),
      zoom: 2,
    });

    this.olmap = new OlMap({
      target: 'map',
      layers: [this.tilelayer,this.vectorlayer],
      view: this.view,
      projection: 'EPSG:3857'
    });

    const selectClick = new Select({
      condition: click,
      layers:[this.vectorlayer]      
    });

    this.olmap.addInteraction(selectClick);    

    selectClick.on(
      'select', ()=>{     
        const values = selectClick.getFeatures().item(0).values_;
        this.getDetails(values.id);                
      }             
    );
} //closes ngOnInit
```

Outside the `ngOnInit`, after the initialization,there are the two different functions that bring geoJSON  to the same ol vector layer. They basically do the same thing.

```
  searchById(id){
    this.map_loading = true;    
    this.myService.getById(id).subscribe((data) =>{
        this.vectorsource.refresh();
        this.vectorsource.clear();
        const fff = (new GeoJSON()).readFeatures(data.data);
        this.vectorsource.addFeatures(fff);
        this.map_loading = false;
    })
  }//searchById
```

and

```
searchCategories(){
    this.map_loading = true;           
this.myService.categoriesSearch(this.categoriesForm.value).subscribe((data) =>{
        this.vectorsource.refresh();
        this.vectorsource.clear();
        const fff = (new GeoJSON()).readFeatures(data.data);
        this.vectorsource.addFeatures(fff);
        this.map_loading = false;
    })
  }//searchCategories
```

**The problem** is that the ol vector source is not always cleared before new features are added. I search for something, features are rendered. I search again , and sometimes, the old features remain on the map, along with the new ones.

I did a silly move to add `refresh` with `clean` and nothing is fixed. This is not standard, eg every other search. This randomly happen and I dont have a clue how to debug it. Please advice

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Is there an unique id for each feature?

I had the same problem that features were loaded constantly. I used the bbox-strategy and every time I moved the map, it loaded all the features in the extent, even if they were already there.

I had to set an unique id in the data for my features, so OpenLayers can refer to the existing ones if you load new ones. This randomness maybe comes through the generated ids for the features, that are sometimes equal to the new ones and sometimes not.

Dont know if that faces your problem, it just flew into my brain while I read that.